# Create a binning variable in r to roll data up on?

Tags: r

I'd like to create a variable that bins values from another variable based on a binwidth

The data would look something like this if I wanted to create a bin variable based on counts where:

```
1 to 5 = 1
6 to 10 = 2
11 to 15 = 3
```

[image]

Without hand recoding each bin is there a function that can do something like this in R?

Comment: Your bins are wrong! look at the last three rows, where the second- and third-last rows put `11` and `12` into bin 1.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you want to get a numeric rather than a factor result, try something like `trunc((mydata$count-1)/5)+1`

e.g.

```
mydata$bucket = trunc((mydata$count-1)/5)+1
```

There's also the `ceiling` function, which is a little simpler:

```
mydata$bucket = ceiling(mydata$count/5)
```

see `?round`

So on your data:

```
mydata = data.frame(spend=c(21,32,34,43,36,39,33,47,47,47,25,50,44,44) ,
                    count=c(3L,1L,2L,15L,1L,8L,1L,11L,15L,11L,3L,12L,11L,4L) )
mydata$bucket = ceiling(mydata$count/5)
```

Which gives:

```
> mydata
   spend count bucket
1     21     3      1
2     32     1      1
3     34     2      1
4     43    15      3
5     36     1      1
6     39     8      2
7     33     1      1
8     47    11      3
9     47    15      3
10    47    11      3
11    25     3      1
12    50    12      3
13    44    11      3
14    44     4      1
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Do you know how you might create the buckets so as to have equal proportions of spend in each bucket?

Comment: Sorry, I see more than one way to interpret "equal proportions of spend in each bucket", so your question isn't unambiguous - indeed it may be better to post this as a new question. Do you mean "equal numbers of observations" or "equal sums over the spend values" or something else?

Comment: Yeah I might post as a new question but I meant equal proportions for the sum or average of spend

Comment: You might be able to get somewhere using weighted quantiles of `count` (using `wtd.quantile` from `Hmisc`), where the weights are based on `spend`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its called the cut function
   ? cut

Comment: Thanks for this I did know about the cut function but was hoping to keep the bucket variable as a continuous variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generic `cut()` function. For a numeric vector `x`, the method has these arguments:

```r
> args(cut.default)
function (x, breaks, labels = NULL, include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE,
    dig.lab = 3L, ordered_result = FALSE, ...)
```

The argument `breaks` is central here. It is *either* a number of intervals *or* a vector of “breakpoints” defining your intervals. Note that *all* intervals are by default right-open (`right = TRUE`), so by creating an object `x`, containing the numbers from 1 to 100 and defining a vector of breakpoints (`brk`) {1, 20, 50, 100}, you will get these results (after using `table()` on the result):

```r
> x <- 1:100
> brk <- c(1,20,50,100)
> table(cut(x = x, breaks = brk))

  (1,20]  (20,50] (50,100]
      19       30       50
```

You can see that the first interval is $(1,\,20]$, so 1 is not part of it and the first observation will become a missing value `NA` (as all other observations outside the defined intervals).
By setting `include.lowest = TRUE`, R includes the lowest value (i.e., the first interval will be closed), so I think this will produce what you want:

```r
> x <- 1:100
> brk <- c(1,20,50,100)
> table(cut(x = x, breaks = brk, include.lowest = TRUE))

  [1,20]  (20,50] (50,100]
      20       30       50
```

The argument `right` reverses the whole process, so intervals are left-open by default and `include.lowest` will close the *last* interval (i.e., include the *highest* value in the last category).

As the resulting object will be of class `"factor"`, you might consider setting `ordered_result` to `TRUE`, producing an ordered factor object (classes `"ordered"` and `"factor"`).
Labelling, etc. is optional (see `?cut`).

Answer (score 0):

The cut function can actually accomplish binning a variable while keeping it as a continuous variable you just need to use the labels parameter:

```
myData$bucket <- cut(myData$counts, breaks = 30, labels = rep(1:30))
```